# jetpack compose - OutlinedTextField errorBorderColor not working

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, textfield, android-compose-textfield

I'm trying to set errorBorderColor of OutlinedTextField to Red but it's not working. Here I give the colors;

```
@Composable
private fun dateTimePickerColors() = TextFieldDefaults.outlinedTextFieldColors(
     errorBorderColor = Color.Red, 
     disabledTextColor = Color.Gray,
     disabledBorderColor = Color.Gray,
     unfocusedBorderColor = Color.Gray,
     focusedBorderColor = Color.Gray,
     containerColor = Color.White,
)

// it gets value from viewModel according to inputs
val isInputError = viewModel.isError.collectAsState
OutlinedTextField(
     //...
     enabled = false 
     colors = dateTimePickerColors()
     isError = isInputError,
)
```

Probably the other colors like `disabledBorderColor` etc. overriding the error color and in the error case, border shows as gray instead of Red;

[image]

so how can i make bordorColor Red?

**Edit:**
When I try this;

```
private fun dateTimePickerColors() = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
    errorIndicatorColor = Color.Red,
    containerColor = Color.White
)
```

[image]

it changes container color instead of border color.

Comment: Did you use isError = true ?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti yes i used

Comment: Can you post the full code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `enabled = false` the `errorBorderColor` is not used.

You have to use **`disabledBorderColor`** using a condition:

```
    val dateTimePickerColors = TextFieldDefaults.outlinedTextFieldColors(
        disabledTextColor = Color.Gray,
        disabledBorderColor = if (isInputError) Color.Red else Color.Gray,
        containerColor = Color.White,
    )

    OutlinedTextField(
        value = text,
        onValueChange = {text = it},
        enabled = false,
        colors = dateTimePickerColors,
        isError = isInputError,
    )
```

[image].
[image]

Comment: outlinedTextFieldColors of material3 is deprecated is there any alternative ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code is `enabled = false` you have to change to `enabaled = true`. Then only `errorBorderColor = Color.Red` will work.

If it is intentional then you can change your  `disabledBorderColor = Color.Gray` to  `disabledBorderColor = Color.Red,` it will work.

Also you can try with `outlinedTextFieldColors`. It works for me.

```
@Composable
private fun dateTimePickerColors() = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
errorIndicatorColor = Color.Red,
....
)
```

Comment: yeah it's working when i make "enabaled = true" but it's intentional. But when i change "disabledBorderColor = Color.Gray" to "disabledBorderColor = Color.Red", it has red border color by default since it's disabled already. And when i try "errorIndicatorColor = Color.Red," it makes container color Red not border color :(

Comment: Oh! It was working for me. We should check more, whats happening there

Comment: i added a screenshot to the edit part of the question about this solution.

Comment: you have to check the condition whether user entered valid input or not according to that you have to change color